# How can I use doctrine to create unique relation?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have 3 tables:

```
table 'user'
 - id
 - name

table 'task'
 - id
 - name

table 'report'
 - id
 - comment
```

I need to create a relationship between table "task", "report "and "user", that report has a unique field "user_id"and "task_id" together, but that "report " would contain many users and tasks.

How can make it via Doctrine?

Comment: Check out doctrine's association mapping. https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It must be like this :

- User->Reports OneToMany
- Task->Reports OneToMany
- Report->User ManyToOne
- Report->Task ManyToOne
- UniqueConstraint in Report with id, user, task fields

For the relations: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

For the UniqueConstraint: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#uniqueconstraint

I didn't test the code...

```php
/**
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity()
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="integer")
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OneToMany(targetEntity="Report", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $reports;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->reports = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // addReport, removeReport, Getters and setters
}

/**
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity()
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table(name="task")
 */
class Task
{
    /**
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="integer")
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OneToMany(targetEntity="Report", mappedBy="task")
     */
    protected $reports;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->reports = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // addReport, removeReport, Getters and setters
}

/**
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity()
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table(name="report",uniqueConstraints={
 *     @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UniqueConstraint(name="report_user_task_idx", columns={"id", "user", "task"})
 * })
 */
class Report
{
    /**
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="integer")
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $comment;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="reports")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Task", inversedBy="reports")
     */
    protected $task;

    // Getters and setters
}
```